# Does Activity method called from Fragment run in the UI thread?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-fragments, ui-thread

I have called an Activity method that updates UI from a Fragment and I get a silent `CalledFromWrongThreadException` that tells me `Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views`.

My Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // ...
    createDynamicView();
} 

public void createDynamicView() {
    // Create some View and attach that to a ViewGroup dynamically as below:
    RelativeLayout rl = new RelativeLayout(this);
    // ...
    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    // ...
    rl.addView(textView, layout_params1);
    layout.addView(rl, layout_params2);
}

// Method called from Fragment
@Override
public void updateLayout() {
    View v = layout.getChaildAt(index); // v is a TextView
    // This line throws a silent Exception:
    // android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: 
    // Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views
    v.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
}
```

Inside fragment:

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try {
        parent = (SettingsInterface) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement SettingsInterface");
    }
}

public void updateLayout() {
    parent.updateLayout();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    webView = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    // ...
    textWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new JSInterface(getActivity()), "Android");
}

public class JSInterface {

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void updateLayout() {
         updateLayout();
    }
}
```

If I put that line inside a `runOnUiThread` block as below:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        v.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    }
});
```

I will not get exception but this could may run after first UI update.
I want to know that does fragment run in a separate thread than UI thread?
and why this exception is silent?

Comment: Please show source how the updateLayout method is called from Fragment

Comment: There is still no information which method in fragment executes the updateLayout(). Please show more code of your fragment

Comment: The method is called from a Javascript interface defined for WebView inside onCreateView. I will update question again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fragments and activities are both running on the main UI thread. Your problem is you are calling your updateLayout() method from a JS thread which is NOT your UI thread. And since you cannot modify the UI components from any other thread than the main UI thread, you will get that exception.

Solution: like you said, use runOnUiThread.

Comment: UI update may run lately. Is there a way to run this code as just as I call the code or force UI update happen without a delay?

Comment: UI thread is continuously running. It does not depend on whether any UI component needs to be refreshed or not. Therefore, your code will run immediately after being called. If you really really need to force UI update -- which is NOT needed for your case - you can use invalidate() method on one of your active UI component, like: View v = findViewById(R.id.some_id); v.invalidate();